# How to bind properties with immutables.org library?

Tags: java, spring, immutability, immutables-library

I know it's possible to have some values bound from a properties file in Spring, like so:

```java
class Foo {

  @Value("${some.config.property}")
  String value;
  ...
}
```

On the current project I'm working for they are keen to use the [immutables library](https://immutables.github.io/).

They have an immutable "class" with some validation that needs some configurable properties. An example:

```java
@Value.Immutable
public interface Foo extends Bar {
    ...
   
    String getValue();

    @Value.Check
    default void validate() {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(getValue().length() <= 2000, //<-- this should be a configurable value
            "Value may not contain more than 2000 characters.");
    }
}
```

This will generate some immutable style class like:

```java
@Generated({"Immutables.generator", "Foo"})
public final class ImmutableFoo implements Foo {
  private final String value;

  private ImmutableFoo(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  
  private static ImmutableFoo validate(ImmutableFoo instance) {
    instance.validate();
    return instance;
  }
}
```

The length of value needs to be configurable for different environments, but I can't seem to figure out to have something configurable in an already existing interface. Is it even possible?